# How do I print the entries of a foreach loop in R?

Tags: r, foreach

I am trying to run an R loop in parallel with foreach.
The idea is that the function called with foreach will take a certain function from a list and use that as a parameter for yet another function.

```
func_list <- c(a(), b(), c())
loop_func <- function(letter){
    obj <- f(parameter = letter)
    return(c(letter, obj)

foreach(val=func_list, .combine='rbind') %dopar% {
    loop_func(val)
} -> result
```

So I am trying to make the loop_func return an output (obj in this case), as well as what function it used as a parameter for the f() function. However, I can not seem to get that function as a string.
I tried `as.character(substitute(letter))`, but that gave me "val".

Is there an intuitive way to get:

```
"a"    obj
```

returned from the function?

Comment: Please provide a minimal reproducible example, i.e., code that if copied into R can be executed without errors. 1. Your `func_list` doesn't appear to be a list of functions. In fact, it is most likely a vector with the return values of these functions. If `a()` doesn't return `"a"`, it's not possible for `loop_func` to get an `"a"`. 2. `loop_func` needs a closing `}` and should probably return a list if you intend to use `obj` later on. 3.  How is `f` defined and what does it return?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `foreach` on a list of function names, and `get` the associated functions:

```
library(foreach)

loop_func <- function(funcname){
  obj <- f(get(funcname))
  return(list(funcname,obj))}

a <- function(x) x
b <- function(x) 2*x
d <- function(x) 3*x

f <- function(func) {func(1)}

func_list <- c("a", "b", "d")

result <- foreach(f = func_list, .combine='rbind') %dopar% {
  loop_func(f)
}

result

         [,1] [,2]
result.1 "a"  1   
result.2 "b"  2   
result.3 "d"  3
```

Comment: @Charles Meijer, did it answer your question?

Comment: It did answer my question, but it was not applicable in my situation. I believe the problem was that my function did not return a certain value, like a() in the example. You could not have known this as I failed to mention that in my question :S. I ended up changing my list of functions to a range of numbers, created a list of functions as well as a list of function name strings within the loop and then just iterated using my list of numbers used in the foreach loop. So you did provide a great answer, but my question was not specific enough. Thank you for your help :D

Comment: Thanks for your feedback and glad you found a solution

Comment: I get this error message: Error in { : task 1 failed - "could not find function "f""

Comment: @stats_noob, I can't reproduce the error you mention

Comment: @ Waldi: In general, I attempting to replicate your approach in this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74759716/r-printing-individual-iterations-from-loops